# Selenium: How do I retry browser/URL when ValueError("No tables found")

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, retry-logic

I have a code that scrapes oddsportal website.

Sometimes while scraping, I get `ValueError("No tables found")` and when I manually refresh browser, page loads.

How do I do it via code?

My code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
    content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'tournamentTable'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
    if main is None:
        return None
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[1].text
    league = count[2].text
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
        game_data.country.append(country)
        game_data.league.append(league)
    return game_data


urls = {
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/page/2/",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/page/3/",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/page/4/",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/page/5/",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/page/6/",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/page/7/",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/page/8/",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/page/9/",

}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    results = None

    for url in urls:
        try:
            game_data = parse_data(url)
            if game_data is None:
                continue
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if results is None:
                results = result
            else:
                results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)
        except ValueError:
            game_data = parse_data(url)
            if game_data is None:
                continue
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if results is None:
                results = result
            else:
                results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)
        except AttributeError:
            game_data = parse_data(url)
            if game_data is None:
                continue
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if results is None:
                results = result
            else:
                results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)
```

Sometimes I get this browser error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/harsh/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/scratches/scratch_29.py", line 10098, in <module>
    game_data = parse_data(url)
  File "C:/Users/harsh/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/scratches/scratch_29.py", line 37, in parse_data
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1100, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only,
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 913, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 893, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 213, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 543, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

My best guess is that I have not built `ValueError: No tables found` in the code correctly.

How do I handle this?

Comment: The error describe itself. `pandas` unable to read table from the `HTML`, You can `try/except` that and save to `.html` file and then view the source code. also i highly recommend to use `selenium` [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) as i do believe that you've use selenium because the data rendered dynamically once the page loads, so you've to wait till the object presented within the page source.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Thats interesting! How can I build that into the code here?

Comment: My buest guess is to Wait for 2 seconds when I encounter this error and retry the URL. How do I code it?

Comment: i already mentioned for you the [selenium-wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) method. But in a simple manner, you can try to `time.sleep(5)` after `browser.get(url)`

Comment: This is ineffecient right? Because I am parsing 75K Urls and waiting 2s or `time.sleep(5)` will take an eternity to complete lol. Isnt trying this only when I encounter the error useful?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη If i understand correctly i.e. `time.sleep(5)` will delay 5s every time it loops regardless of error or not?

Comment: That,s correct, so you can except the error and sleep. then read.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη This is exactly my question. Apologies that I cannot explain it much discreetly. How do I build it in the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234591/discussion-between-pynoob-n-and--c).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

urls = [
    "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results"
]


def main(driver):
    for url in urls:
        driver.get(url)
        waiter = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        try:
            waiter.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.ID, 'tournamentTable')))
            df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, attrs={
                              'id': 'tournamentTable'})[0].iloc[:, :-1]
            df.dropna(inplace=True)
            df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
            return df

        except TimeoutException:
            print('Unable to Find Table')
        finally:
            driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    df = main(driver)
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Soccer» Africa»Africa Cup of Nations
            15 Jun 2021 - Qualification  15 Jun 2021 - Qualification.1 15 Jun 2021 - Qualification.2      1      X      2
0                                 16:00           Sierra Leone - Benin                           1:0   2.85   2.85   2.63
1           30 Mar 2021 - Qualification    30 Mar 2021 - Qualification   30 Mar 2021 - Qualification      1      X      2
2                                 19:00              Cameroon - Rwanda                           0:0   1.51   3.59   7.78
3                                 19:00              Morocco - Burundi                           1:0   1.15   6.63  22.58
4                                 19:00        Mozambique - Cape Verde                           0:1   2.66   2.96   2.81
5                                 16:00          Guinea Bissau - Congo                           3:0   2.64   2.81   3.01
6                                 16:00              Nigeria - Lesotho                           3:0   1.13   7.78  20.49
7                                 16:00             Senegal - Eswatini                           1:1   1.05  12.78  30.79
8                                 13:00    Central Africa - Mauritania                           0:1   1.96   3.12   4.11
9                                 13:00         Ivory Coast - Ethiopia                           3:1   1.61   2.85   9.43
10                                13:00             Madagascar - Niger                           0:0   1.20   6.36  13.98
11          29 Mar 2021 - Qualification    29 Mar 2021 - Qualification   29 Mar 2021 - Qualification      1      X      2
12                                19:00             Algeria - Botswana                           5:0   1.11   7.75  26.29
13                                19:00              Zimbabwe - Zambia                           0:2   2.92   3.02   2.49
14                                16:00                 Angola - Gabon                           2:0   3.08   2.84   2.55
15                                16:00     Burkina Faso - South Sudan                           1:0   1.16   6.56  18.56
16                                16:00            D.R. Congo - Gambia                           1:0   1.89   3.25   4.30
17                                16:00                Egypt - Comoros                           4:0   1.28   4.70  12.98
18                                16:00                   Togo - Kenya                           1:2   2.11   2.70   4.44
19                                13:00                Malawi - Uganda                           1:0   3.28   2.58   2.62
20          28 Mar 2021 - Qualification    28 Mar 2021 - Qualification   28 Mar 2021 - Qualification      1      X      2
21                                16:00  Ghana - Sao Tome and Principe                           3:1   1.05  12.65  28.43
22                                16:00           Sudan - South Africa                           2:0   3.66   3.09   2.10
23                                13:00               Namibia - Guinea                           2:1   3.32   2.85   2.38
24                                13:00               Tanzania - Libya                           1:0   2.50   2.80   3.20
25                                13:00    Tunisia - Equatorial Guinea                           2:1   1.27   5.07  11.87
26          27 Mar 2021 - Qualification    27 Mar 2021 - Qualification   27 Mar 2021 - Qualification      1      X      2
27                                16:00                Benin - Nigeria                           0:1   4.45   2.37   2.30
28                                13:00         Lesotho - Sierra Leone                           0:0   2.71   2.50   3.25
29          26 Mar 2021 - Qualification    26 Mar 2021 - Qualification   26 Mar 2021 - Qualification      1      X      2
30                                19:00           Mauritania - Morocco                           0:0   9.09   3.96   1.40
31                                16:00          Cape Verde - Cameroon                           3:1   2.92   2.69   2.79
32                                16:00                Congo - Senegal                           0:0   7.29   3.50   1.54
33                                16:00            Niger - Ivory Coast                           0:3  11.28   4.38   1.33
34                                13:00       Burundi - Central Africa                           2:2   1.86   3.16   4.42
35                                13:00       Eswatini - Guinea Bissau                           1:3   6.42   3.35   1.60
36          25 Mar 2021 - Qualification    25 Mar 2021 - Qualification   25 Mar 2021 - Qualification      1      X      2
37                                19:00   Equatorial Guinea - Tanzania                           1:0   2.13   2.76   4.10
38                                19:00                Libya - Tunisia                           2:5   3.98   3.03   2.03
39                                19:00               Zambia - Algeria                           3:3   3.95   3.06   2.02
40                                16:00            Botswana - Zimbabwe                           0:1   2.44   2.58   3.64
41                                16:00             Gabon - D.R. Congo                           3:0   2.33   2.75   3.59
42                                16:00                Gambia - Angola                           1:0   1.97   2.86   4.58
43                                16:00                  Kenya - Egypt                           1:1   6.24   3.39   1.61
44                                16:00           South Africa - Ghana                           1:1   2.47   2.77   3.31
45                                13:00                 Comoros - Togo                           0:0   1.56   3.63   6.13
46          24 Mar 2021 - Qualification    24 Mar 2021 - Qualification   24 Mar 2021 - Qualification      1      X      2
47                                16:00                  Guinea - Mali                           1:0   1.66   3.19   6.25
48                                13:00                 Chad - Namibia                        award.      -      -      -
49                                13:00          Ethiopia - Madagascar                           4:0   2.16   2.99   3.59
50                                13:00            Rwanda - Mozambique                           1:0   2.30   2.78   3.52
51                                13:00  Sao Tome and Principe - Sudan                           0:2   7.31   3.44   1.54
52                                13:00           South Sudan - Malawi                           0:1   2.78   2.58   3.06
53                                13:00          Uganda - Burkina Faso                           0:0   2.75   2.46   3.31
54          17 Nov 2020 - Qualification    17 Nov 2020 - Qualification   17 Nov 2020 - Qualification      1      X      2
55                                19:00                 Namibia - Mali                           1:2   5.22   3.30   1.72
56                                19:00             Tanzania - Tunisia                           1:1   5.04   3.42   1.71
57                                16:00            Angola - D.R. Congo                           0:1   3.19   2.84   2.41
```

Comment: This is great! Would adding this part of the code make the error handling I have written redundant?

Comment: Does `except KeyError:
            browser.quit()` cause the browser to quit? Shouldnt it be `except KeyError:
            browser.retry()` ?

Comment: @PyNoob_N we are closing the page and reopening it once the issue happens. also you can send `refresh` to refresh the page and keep trying. but i highly recommend to use selenium wait. on the other side, your entire code looks uncomfortable for me. i will review it later shortly.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! I would request you to review and improve the code for the cause of SO community. The code is just stitched together from solutions posted here as I am not good with development (at all!). I (think) understand the logic but to build the code is another matter altogether. Also, I am **IMMENSELY** grateful for the community which helps me develop and progress. **THANK YOU**

Comment: @PyNoob_N you welcome but be informed that `StackOver Flow`! isn't a code writing service. your questions is messing a basic understanding of the language itself, without showing effort or even limit your post to a specific problem that's will not be helpful for contributors to help you. However i posted a sample answer for your question. But kindly make sure to read [ask] and how to provide [mcve]

Comment: You are correct again! I dont think SO is a code writing service at all! It is a group of coding enthisuiasts helping each other. Of course the term 'help' can be exploited to the extent of a 'code writing service' but that has never been an endavour of mine. Also, it is not my place to provide feedback on how can we avoid getting there. I have learnt so much over here. Me personally, am a Mechanical Engineer by profession and has never learnt to code in school. I dont use code at work as well. Again, as always, I am so thankful for this community and yourself.

Comment: The output of this code is grouped by and the output is specifically required in [this format and schema](https://pastebin.com/gMhQJD9s) How can I modify the code?